# Forçar abrir Facebook/Twitter/Google no browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, facebook, twitter-api

Criei um app para mobile que é acessado via browser (um Web app, um site comum).

Nele tenho um botão que abre via window.open() uma página no Facebook, porém quando clico no botão, ele chama o aplicativo do Facebook.
Eu preciso que a página abra no próprio navegador do celular.

já tentei como window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes'), mas não funciona, acho que só serve para apps instalados.

Existe alguma solução?

Comment: Oi Paulo, é um Web app, um site.

Comment: Só queria abrir uma página do Facebook no próprio navegador do Android, mas quando clico no botão ele pergunta se quero abrir com o App do Facebook ou com o navegador. Queria abrir direto com o navegador, sem perguntar. Será que tem como?

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto,

HTML:

```html
<div id="teste" data-href="http://www.google.com">Google</div>
```

JavaScript:

```css
document.getElementById("teste").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("data-href"));
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    var dispatch = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    dispatch.initEvent("click", true, true);
    a.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
}, false);
```

Qualquer coisa posta aí.